# How to call a controller function in jquery after a button click in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, controller, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to call a function from a controller to store some data in a database after a button click.  Namely, in the javascript (jquery), I have:

```
$( '.opener' ).click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
                // redirect_uri: '/index.php',
            link: 'http://test.com',
            name: 'Bleh',
            caption: 'Blah',
            description: 'Testing!'
            // {{$artist->stage_name}} 
            });

        // Want to call controller function here:
         {{Artists:function}}


      });
```

How do I call the function from the controller in this case?  In the above case the controller would be ArtistsController, and the function "function".   Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just link to it like a normal URL - something like this:

```
$( '.opener' ).click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://test.com/artists/function', // put the link here
            name: 'Bleh',
            caption: 'Blah',
            description: 'Testing!'
            });
      });
```

And in your routes.php

```
Route::get('/artists/function', array('uses' => 'ArtistsController@function'));
```

Comment: would that call the function "function" in the artists controller?

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to

```
Route::get('artists/function', array('as' => 'artists/function', 'uses' => 'ArtistsController@function'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for example with DB class declared into `Controller` but you can do it directly without route:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>home.blade.php</h1>
  <?php 
   function test(){ 
    $users = DB::table('users')->join('users_views', 'users.id', '=', 'users_views.id')->where('users_views.id',Auth::user()->id)-‌​>get(); foreach ($users as $permiso) { $ck2 = $permiso->perm; } 
   } 
   test(); 
   echo ";)"; 
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <html><body><h1>home.blade.php</h1><?php 
function test(){
$users = DB::table('users')->join('users_views', 'users.id', '=', 'users_views.id')->where('users_views.id',Auth::user()->id)->get();

        foreach ($users as $permiso)
    {
      $ck2 = $permiso->perm;
     
  } 

}
test();  echo ";)";
?></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    function get_fotos_productos($id_prod){
        //here call DB Class 
        foreach ($fotos as $foto)
        {
            $foto='<img src="img/productos/big/'.$foto->foto.'" width="50" alt="">';
            echo  $foto;
        } 

 } ?>
```

for example in my view

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 7 - Items<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">

        <?php 
        $id_prod=3;
        foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {

            echo '                          
            <li>
                <span class="item">
                    <span class="item-left">
                        '. get_fotos_productos($id_prod).'        
                        <span class="item-info">
                            <span>Codigo :'.$value["code"].'</span>
                            <span>Cantidad : '.$value["qty"].'</span>            
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="item-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right">x</button>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </li>
            ';        

         }
         ?>
         <li class="divider">
         <li><?php echo "Costo Total:".$total; ?></li>
         <li><a class="text-center" href="">View Cart</a></li>
      </ul>

    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: $fotos = DB:: table('productos')->where('id','=',$id_prod)->get();